# asp.net visual studio can't recognize the id

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

This is my asp code

```
<tr class="footer" runat="server">
                            <td colspan="4" runat="server">* By WWW.Play.org
                               <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="callDispositionSelector" OnSelectedIndexChanged="callDispositionChanged">
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Disposition Reason</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Change of Reservation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Cancellation</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Wait List</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem Value="5">Other</asp:ListItem>
                               </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

In code behind, I am not able to type this `callDispositionSelector`. In other words, visual studio doesn't recognize that id.

I tried clean, rebuild, restart visual stuidio but nothing helps.

I tried change the id to another name but still not recognizable.

I tried deting the designer , and then regenerate it but still the same problem

Comment: create new page and copy paste all code to new page and check ..it ..let me know if not work..

Comment: @AnantDabhi i tried, but still vs not recognize the id

Comment: do you see that control "callDispositionSelector " in  browser?

Comment: @Ajay yes for sure, i see it

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing out your the temp compiled page cache, both the 32-bit and 64-bit respective directories (64-bit shown below):

```
%System Drive%:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

That sometimes can do the trick

**Solution 2.**

solved it by restarting VS (which it looks like you've tried) or checking the class names in the front end code and back and code are the same.

It sounds like a stupid thing, but if you copy a page, then the class name doesn't update so the bindings go a little skewiffy (that's a technical term).

Comment: I have to delete all the files and folders inside the `v4.0.30319` ? I am afraid that this may crash another thing, please tell me